# how to consume webpack library in webpack application

Tags: angular, webpack, bundle, umd

I m working on angular2 + typescript application.

I see how @angular packages works:

If you install `@angular/common`, you ll have in your `node_modules` folder:

```
@angular/core
  |---bundles
  |    |---core.umd.js
  |
  |---src (all transpiled code)
  |---index.js
```

So, thanks to `index.js`.... and all the transpiled code in `src`, 
Imports like

`import { NgModule } from "@angular/core";` let me compile the application;

But,in my output/dist folder, I have **NO** `index.js` and **NO** transpiled file, thanks to SystemJs that make pretty simple to consume a `.umd.js` library:

```
(function (global) {
  System.config({
    paths: {
      // paths serve as alias
      'npm:': 'node_modules/'
    },
    // map tells the System loader where to look for things
    map: {
      // our app is within the app folder
      app: '',
      // angular bundles
      '@angular/core': 'lib/@angular/core/bundles/core.umd.js',
      '@angular/common': 'lib/@angular/common/bundles/common.umd.js',
      'mylib1': 'lib/mylib1/bundles/mybundlelib1.umd.js',
      'mylib2: 'lib/mylib2/bundles/mybundlelib2.umd.js',
      .........................
      .........................
```

What I'm looking for is way to do the same even with webpack;

I have some library/bundle create by myself with webpack, and I want to consume them in my webpack application.

in `node_modules` folder of application I'll have same structure as angular packages:

```
mylib1
  |---bundles
  |    |---mybundlelib.umd.js
  |
  |---src (all transpiled code)
  |---index.js
```

so i can use `index.js` and `src` to compile statement like

`import { libClass } from "mylib1";`....but...

As for SystemJs I'll take care of copy the JUST bundles in my output/dist folder, and...

1) I don't want to put them into the Vendor bundle;

2) I don't want to use their transpiled code to create a new bundle via webpack configuration of application.

Can you help me ??

To be More Specific, I just want to use third party libraries with my webpack application;

So, close to `app.js`, `vendor.js`, `index.html` and whatever other part of my application, I want to have some externals bundle libraries to consume them.

Comment: Inventing the wheel?

Comment: have I to laugh ??

Comment: Can you make your question more specific?